# Insulating an open window with air conditioning pipe through it

Tags: insulation, windows, air-conditioning

I seek to install an on-floor AC and pipe its exhaust through a window (images below). The window is double, lower window being taller, and is elevated way above the origin exhaust pipe.

I'm thinking of keeping the lower window open and poking a hole through the net (or ridding of net entirely), while insulating the rest.

1. How do I go about insulating? What materials? It should keep out heat, cold, and bugs, while the window is open, and while keeping the top window openable.
2. Does the exhaust piping physics work out? Will I need a pump to make it flow up about half a meter?

(3) Anything obvious I'm missing? DIY newbie

[image]

**Edit**: thanks all, I decided I'll suffer instead

Thanks @KMJ for an [important video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc) on why single-hosed sucks, and I couldn't find anything else that either works in my setup or is affordable. I decided I'll move the fan to point blank range; turns out, not so bad, fan + sweat = cool

Comment: why is all of stack exchange interested in my AC issues

Comment: Are you in a ground floor unit?

Comment: The more people interested in your question, the more likely you are to get a good answer. Not sure I see the issue...

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon because it was detected by the algorithm as "hot" (the irony), and promoted in the sidebar.

Comment: If and when you replace this unit, seek out a double hose model, which are significantly more efficient.

Comment: FYI: If you can stop outside air from getting in to the room, then that unit will not work at all. It's got only one hose going through the window. In order to cool the "hot" side of the heat pump, it sucks air _from inside the room_ through the hot coils, and then sends it out through the hose. But it _can't_ suck air from inside the room unless there's some way for outside air to _enter_ the room and replace what was sucked out. _Warm_ outside air. A _two_ hose unit cools the "hot" coils by sucking outside air in through one hose, and then expelling it out through the other hose.

Comment: [Example two hose unit](https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Conditioner-Self-Evaporative-Operation-Dehumidifying/dp/B09MWM73NN/). Not a recommendation. I have no idea if it's actually any good. I'm just including the link to prove that such things exist. But if it _was_ any good, then it would be way more efficient than your one-hose machine.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think the chance of sealing the room that well is pretty close to nil.  I would just be worried about pulling the exhaust in.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon everyone is here because your post hit the HNQ.  Congrats !

Comment: @Huesmann nopeㅤ

Comment: @SolomonSlow The air inside rest of the apartment is considerably cooler than what comes straight through the sunlit window, but yes I've no intent to seal off the entire room

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exhaust of your unit is warm air and is not adversely affected by the elevation change. Up is better when it comes to warm air, but not by a significant amount. I have a similar unit and exhaust through a sliding window, the sill of which is also above the exhaust port of the unit.

I used a large slab of Coroplast™, a corrugated plastic panel. It is not known for insulating properties, but for the period of use, that is not a factor in my decision for mounting.

If insulation is important to you, foam insulation panels of various thicknesses are available at big-box stores. They can be considered fragile and if that is a concern, can be bonded with adhesive to a carrier panel of thinner plywood.

It's uncertain why you think a pump is required. There should be no liquid involved in the exhaust. You will want to consider where and how to remove the condensate generated by the unit. There should be a tubing fitting at a fairly low level, although my unit has this drain at about half-way, allowing the hose to gravity drain into a storage bin, which necessitates manual dumping at least on a daily basis.

Comment: I just realized, rain - I was also thinking foam but clearly that won't suffice. Plywood + foam... makes sense. Though, I was hoping there's a material I won't have to saw through, that's also weather-proof and readily consumer-available - like a foam with plywood impermeability - I guess no such thing?

Comment: ... foam wrapped with layers of plastic bags?

Comment: The typical foam panel from the home improvement stores will / can have foil on one or both sides, which is, if undamaged, water resistant. The edges are raw foam, but will not absorb water (much).  Regardless of your choice of panel, you'll have to saw through it, although one can use a pocket knife to saw through insulating foam!

Comment: Other answers are fine, I accepted this with comments considered as I seek the most peasant-friendly variant

Answer (score 11):

Rigid foam.

It's fairly inexpensive and you can cut it to fit easily.

Temps here have been around 100°F, I used a 1" foam, and used a 4" PVC pipe instead of the accordion vent pipe supplied with the unit. Our room easily stays in the low 70°s F.

Once the foam is installed, you can tape the perimeter to the window frame or leave it off. Mine isn't taped and has very minimal air leakage, plus we are still able to open the window at night once it cools down.

Also, I would leave the window screen intact, no need to cut or remove, the air will easily pass through it.

[image: rigid foam insulation]

Here is a picture of my current install.

[image: air conditioner install with rigid foam insulation]

Answer (score 5):

Check if the manufacturer makes a window kit. They normally include a 'fish-tail' which fits into a sealing strip, meaning the window doesn't have to be quite so wide open as with the full pipe diameter.
I've had about 4 of these units over the past 20 years or so, & they all came with a kit in the box.

If not, there are many third party kits.

As mentioned… rain. Mine is like the first design here, so I don't have to worry so much if it rains. You could always make a small sloped 'roof' just over the exhaust using a spare bit of the plastic insert [they always supply too much.]
I also use triangular soft foam fillets on the side gaps, using velcro dots to gently hold them in place, & so they can be easily removed. The advantage of soft foam is you can pull the window in tight to trap it, and your cut doesn't have to be absolutely perfect.
I also have neoprene foam sealant tape along the edges of the plastic insert.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You'll probably find that the manufacturer will only guarantee the unit if the pipe is dead straight from unit to window, and also as short as possible - but I doubt there are many people who can actually achieve that.
Just try not to have it stretch too far, or turn a lot of corners. Every corner and every foot of pipe reduces the unit's efficiency.
The unit itself can push hot air out the back just about as fast as it pushes cold air out the front; the reduction in efficiency on a convoluted path there's really nothing you can do about, the corrugated pipe makes for turbulence - again, same front & rear if your unit has a front pipe you can swap in. You can't add an extra blower easily.

Check the condensate drain tap daily, until you get a feel for how often it may need draining. Some need emptying all the time, some never. My last couple of units have never needed manual draining, they re-evaporate it & blow it outdoors. If you have this type of unit, then you just check if there's any water left in it before you put it away for the winter.

Oh, one last thing that's always a tad irritating… they always seem to be left-hand thread, maybe just to catch you out.

Answer (score 3):

Products for windows like yours start to appear. In my country, one can find this:

[image: accesory for window that opens laterally]

Link (in French): https://www.doitgarden.ch/fr/p/614224500000/sonnenkoenig-kit-fenetre-accessoire-per-evacuation-de-l-air

Searching on Google Images for "window air evacuation accessory ac" returns results that are similar to the above. You can use these to find a provider that ships to you.

Comment: hmm, so the peasant variant would be a large insulating cloth to wrap the window... neat.

Comment: Perhaps it only works with windows that open inwards?

Comment: I have the same thing, and I wouldn't call it the peasant variant - it came with some velcro glued to the window and the frame, so the cloth part is removable, and when you take the hose out you can still open and close the window. Works well for me. My version has a thick middle and thin ends because it's intended to work with inwards opening windows, but there are versions for sliding windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a double glazed window and the outlet from the tumble drier. Solved by taking out the glazing unit, and replacing with two sheets of perspex, using hardwood round the edges to get the appropriate thickness to re-fit. Cut two holes - one in each pane, for a spigot which leads to a flap on the outside.

I could (should?) have sealed all the joints, but it all works fine without. The window will still open, with or without the 4" pipe attached.

Comment: Take the pane out, +1. Now it's just a square hole in a building, which is the ideal shape to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to me that insulation is really going to make much difference here.
What I think you need to focus on is sealing the opening so to limit the air infiltration.  The air coming out of that hose will be hot and you want to avoid it coming back into the room.  AS long as it stays outside, it should rise up and away on its own.

I also don't see a lot of need to remove the screen (or 'net').  The hot air should pass through it as long as it is relatively free of dust and debris.

From the picture, it seems to me that the top window has an edge that hangs over the bottom part.  If that's right, I'm not seeing how you keep the top part closed while the bottom is open.

What I would do, (if aesthetics are not a concern) is remove the bottom window from the hinges.  Get a decent piece of plywood (a thin board should be fine) and trace the shape of the lower window on it.  Cut the plywood to shape such that it fits snugly where the lower was.  Next cut a round hole in the board that the exhaust (or extension) pipe fits tightly.  Place the board in the lower part of the window and tape any gaps.  This gives you an opportunity to secure against intrusion if that's a concern.  Choose your tape wisely here: duct tape seems like an obvious solution but will create a very sticky, gummy mess; especially if it's left in place for a while.  Connect the exhaust and you should be set.  When the cooling season ends, you can then remove the board and put the lower window back.